# How can I pick the last item of Property in powershell?

Tags: powershell

Here is my code:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName PresentationCore
[Windows.Media.Fonts]::SystemFontFamilies | Select-Object -Property Source,FamilyNames
```

Actually, the property FamilyNames has many items and I only want to pick the last one.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: `Select-Object` has a `-Last` parameter. Simple look at the documentation would've answered this

Comment: If I modify my code like this:[Windows.Media.Fonts]::SystemFontFamilies | Select-Object -Property Source,FamilyNames -Last 1. It will only return the last item of the SystemFontFamilies but not the last item of FamilyNames. @SantiagoSquarzon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not want to list the last SystemFontFamilies, like you stated in your comment. You seem to want to select the property `Source` and the last entry in `FamilyNames`. If you examine what's contained within `FamilyNames`, you'll see it's a dictionary object.

```
[Windows.Media.Fonts]::SystemFontFamilies | Select-Object -expandProperty FamilyNames | Get-Member

TypeName: System.Windows.Media.LanguageSpecificStringDictionary
```

A dictionary will contain keys and values. If you inspect the keys/values, you should see something like this.

```
[Windows.Media.Fonts]::SystemFontFamilies | Select-Object -expandProperty FamilyNames

Name                           Value
----                           -----
en-us                          Cascadia Code
en-us                          Cascadia Mono
```

It seems you want to select the last value in `Keys` so I would use a [calculated property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_calculated_properties?view=powershell-7.3) to pull the desired info

```
[Windows.Media.Fonts]::SystemFontFamilies |
    Select-Object -Property Source,
                            @{n='FamilyNames';e={$_.FamilyNames.Keys | Select-Object -Last 1}}
```